# How To Change Background Image by Time of Day Without Page-Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm looking to achieve is having the background image of my page change based on the hour of the day. This is fairly easy, as it only requires retrieving the hour through the Date object, and checking it's value.

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if (hour < 9 || hour > 18) {
    //set image through url
} else {
    //set another image through url
}
```

What I'm actually looking for is to have the background image change dynamically (no page refresh). I have come up with a method that does this with the above logic, but I believe it loads the image with every passing interval:

```
setInterval(function () {
     var hours = new Date().getHours();
     $("#hours").html((hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours);

     if (hours > 9 && hours < 18) {
          $("body").css("background-image", "url(../images/night-sky-background.jpg)");
     } else {
          $("body").css("background-image", "url(../images/day-sky-background.jpg)");
     }
}, 1000);
```

The above code writes the `hours` value to the page and will check it's value every second with the interval. It also checks the value of `hours` every second and will set the background image accordingly. I'm afraid this is actually not a good way to approach this. Here's why:

[Fiddle of second-by-second interval](http://jsfiddle.net/brf6yw99/)

I have a feeling it is actually setting the background image every second which would result in terrible performance.

Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: Why not set it on page load? Are you expecting users to spend a long time on a single page?

Comment: You can increase the interval to once every hour. An hour is 3600 seconds, so you can set it to interval every 3600000 miliseconds

Comment: @eskimo I wouldn't expect a user to be on any page for a long time. This is more of a question to satisfy a hypothetical curiosity. Would be pretty cool to be on the page and see the image shift.

Comment: Another option is to check the hour and set the setTimeout exactly after the hour shift

Comment: Wait a second, how is it possible that `if (hour < 9 && hour > 18)` is evaluating? I don't think that the very first code piece will work.

Comment: @briosheje in which block of code? The second one evaluates just fine. The first one should, but was more of a pseudo-code example anyway.

Comment: less than 9 and greater than 18 works?....

Comment: @DrewKennedy: Yes, the second one does, but the first doesn't. How is it supposed to be lower than 9 and higher than 18 at the same time? in any case, just a little idea: instead of checking the seconds, get the SECONDS that remains until the very next hour. In this way you will only have a timer and an interval, not an endless loop that will be called each second :).. And, of course, set the background onload before displaying the page.

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut nice catch. will update.

Comment: i think @briosheje caught it first

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut: It's totally okay, regardless who caught it he didn't correct it though.. I mean, he corrected the second if replacing the && with the ||, but the second if was okay! :P EDIT: ok now it's right :)

Comment: @briosheje Thisn is what happens when you're bored at work. ;)

Comment: Shouldn't it be hour > 9 && hour < 18? I don't see why you need an OR condition, if it is 7 the if will evaluate, because it is LOWER than 9 but also LOWER than 18, therefore the second statement will be true, and 0 or 1 evaluates to 1, which will be true, which is NOT what you want, right?.. I mean, if I'm not going mad hours > 9 || hours < 18 will always evaluate to true. Oh. you edited it now. The answer below didn't, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the current background URL before updating it?

```
setInterval(function () {
     var hours = new Date().getHours();
     $("#hours").html((hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours);

     if (hours > 9 && hours < 18) {
          if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("night-sky-background.jpg")==-1){
              $("body").css("background-image", "url(../images/night-sky-background.jpg)");
          }
     } else {
          if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("day-sky-background.jpg")==-1){
             $("body").css("background-image", "url(../images/day-sky-background.jpg)");
          }
     }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I think using a variable to keep state is better performance wise then checking the image everytime.

Comment: It is definitely better to use a variable but at least they are only checking at 1 second intervals so it shouldn't be a huge deal.

Comment: True.  Another approach would be to get the time, then setTimeout for however long until the "day/night" switch.

Comment: Just missing a couple closing brackets there. If I throw in a `console.log()` after your inner `if-statements` it still prints out every second, thus still setting the background-image every second, no?

Comment: 1000 milliseconds is one second, look at the if statements.  He is checking first before setting the image.

Comment: Updated now to fix that

Comment: Okay I see what's going on now. Thanks @nvuono and everyone else for the help. :)